# About resume format for one year's worth of experience in developing

Tags: resume, job-search

I need to know what is all the content needed on a CV while searching for a job, when you only have a year of experience?

Comment: This is just too broad....do you have any specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous answers stated about contents already.

Other aspect we need to take care is format/structure of a CV. Try to make it as plain as possible so that machine can read those CVs effectively. When many people are interested in a job, companies will certainly take some or more help from machine's recommendations. As CV format online today, is mostly for traditional use, it's better to update future CVs for machine's use. Some tips

1. Make sure you have proper headers like summary, experience,
   education, skills, certification etc.
2. Use uppercase or bold to distinct headers from rest of text.
3. Separate headers and paragraphs with good spacing and newline.
4. Avoid using columns, unless its a picture, it's harder to read.
   Columns and different topics on the same row with multiple columns add no
   value.
5. Proper usage of commas and full stops.
6. Try to have similar patterns inside headers like
   {university},{location},{degree},{date} can span on multiple lines but having a similar pattern is really helpful.
7. If you were to use a table, use it with proper headers but best avoid
   it, try to make the CV as simple and linear as possible.

*Bonus: Stop being creative in the CV, keep it plain simple.*

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the intent of a CV really does not change over time - it is a document that reflects your knowledge, experience, capabilities, and a brief summary of achievements.

Over period, more bullets get added to each of those categories (to show your experience and expertise and achievements), but the categories remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write everything which is relevant for the recruiter, for the job that you apply.

Write the required personal information (name, contact information), write about your education, your job(s). Even projects that you did in your free time, if it applies.

I wrote [**here**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/129602/98881) an answer about the topic.

---

Of course, being at the beginning of your career, the CV will be shorter, compared tot he CV's of people with a lot of experience. But that is not the point. The point is to sell yourself in the best way possible, and mention there everything that is related to the position you apply for.

You should write about the results you had in school, projects which you worked on during school and during your free time, internships, scholarships, student exchange experiences. Also, mention the job-related information: projects, technologies, tools that you used, processes that you applied, original ideas that you had... All of that matters to a recruiter, because they can have a better understanding of who you are and what you can.

Also: how you handled requirements, how you tested, what you did when a problem was reported, how you handled crisis situations (if any), cooperation with your colleagues, your role in the team...